Custom checkbox triggers twice
I have this template for a custom checkbox input:
<label *ngIf="grouped"
    class="field-check"
    [class.field-error]="errors"
    [class.no-events]="readonly">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputTmp"
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{}"></ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="labeled">
        <span *ngIf="!labelTemplate" class="field-check--slabel" [ngClass]="inxs" [innerHTML]="label"></span>
        <div *ngIf="labelTemplate" class="field-check--temp">
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="labelTemplate"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{}"></ng-container>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</label>

<div *ngIf="!grouped"
    class="field-check"
    [class.no-events]="readonly">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputTmp"
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{}"></ng-container>
    <span *ngIf="!labelTemplate" [ngClass]="inxs" [innerHTML]="label"></span>
    <div *ngIf="labelTemplate" class="field-check--temp" [ngClass]="inxs">
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="labelTemplate"
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{}"></ng-container>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #inputTmp>
    <div class="ultim-checkbox"
        [class.readonly]="readonly || disabled"
        [class.checked]="checked"
        [class.intermediate]="intermediate"
        (click)="toggleCheck($event)">
        <input type="checkbox"
            tabindex="0"
            [required]="required"
            [ngModel]="value"
            [disabled]="disabled"
            [attr.intermediate]="intermediate || null"
            #fieldInput="ngModel"
            #cb>
        <span><i class="ico"
                [ngClass]="{
                    'i-check-fat': !intermediate,
                    'i-minus-fat': intermediate
                }"></i></span>
    </div>
</ng-template>

When clicking on a label (HTML element 'label' or the span element containing the label for the checkbox), it all goes as expected. When clicking directly on a the 'ico' icon, the click event gets triggered twice. The result is that the checkbox stays visibly unchanged, as it is being set to two opposite values within the same human interaction.
event.target for the first event is an '.ico'  element and the target for the second one is the input element which is actually hidden.
Here is the component's code
public toggleCheck(event: MouseEvent): any {

    if ( this.checkboxGroup ) {
        this.checkboxGroup.addOrRemove(this.value);
    } else {
        this.value = !this.value;
    }

    this.intermediate = false;
}

Here is a CSS code for the input element (if this helps)
.field-check .ultim-checkbox input {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    z-index: 0;
}

If I add event.stopPropagation() or event.preventDefault() then change event stops working completely:
<!-- doSomething is never called -->
<custom-checkbox (change)="doSomething($event)"></custom-checkbox>

and while checkbox is visibly changing, the missing change event does not trigger data changes (like, RxJS, API et al).
Any ideas, why it is triggering twice?

Clicking on label triggers click on input element, it's the standard behavior, which causes click to be called twice.
In first ngIf, you have it wrapped in a label, and the other is not.
Try removing label from first parent container, and turning span into label, and moving input inside, and move toggleCheck on input, that way click should be triggered only once, allowing checkbox to change with clicking both on label or input:
<div *ngIf="grouped">
...


<div *ngIf="!grouped">
...

...    
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"

           (click)="toggleCheck($event)"
            tabindex="0"
            [required]="required"
            [ngModel]="value"
            [disabled]="disabled"
            [attr.intermediate]="intermediate || null"
            #fieldInput="ngModel"
            #cb>
        <i class="ico"
                [ngClass]="{
                    'i-check-fat': !intermediate,
                    'i-minus-fat': intermediate
                }"></i>


                </label>


Thanks for the answer. I've tried your variant and it didn't work, so I've decided to do something different entirely. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78419114/542191

I have a strong feeling that it happens because of [ngModel] on the Input element. You use it to set the value of the value :) and then you set it (in reality revert it) again in toggleCheck() function.
<div 
  class="ultim-checkbox" 
  [class.readonly]="readonly || disabled" 
  [class.checked]="checked" 
  [class.intermediate]="intermediate" 
  (click)="toggleCheck($event)">
  <!-- Either remove ngModel >
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    tabindex="0"
    [required]="required"
    [ngModel]="REMOVE_ME"
  />
  <span>
    <!-- ... --> 
  </span>
</div>

Or don't do this:
public toggleCheck(event: MouseEvent): any {
  if (this.checkboxGroup) {
    this.checkboxGroup.addOrRemove(this.value);
  } else {
    // Or don't set the value here 
    // Although I'm not sure how the condition above affects this.
    this.value = !this.value;
  }
  this.intermediate = false;
}


Thanks for the answer. I've tried both of the options you've offered, none of it worked, so I went with something different (see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78419114/542191 )

Unfortunately, none of the solutions has worked so I've went with something entirely different. I've added quasi-custom change event and did the following:
@Output() public readonly change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

public toggleCheck(event: MouseEvent): void {

    if ( this.checkboxGroup ) {
        this.checkboxGroup.addOrRemove(this.value);
    } else {
        this.value = !this.value;
    }

    this.intermediate = false;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    this.propagateChange(this.value);
    this.change.emit(this.value);
}

I might come back to this at some point in the future and try to find a more elegant solution, but for now it works alright.
